# how to apply click action for a loaded button

Tags: jquery

I've 2 pages, the main one has a click action for button's id which is loaded from anothe page"1.php". The click job isn't working.
the main file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#t").load("1.php");
      $("#s").click(function () {
         alert($("Done!");
      });
   });
</script>
<div id="t"></div>
```

and here's 1.php:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="go" id="s">';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: still not working!! could it be from my jquery edition?

Comment: OK, now the main page:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#t").load("1.php");
        $("#t").on("click", "#s", function() {
 alert("Done!");
 });
 });</script>
 <div id="t"></div>

and here's 1.php:
echo '
<input type="button" value="go" id="s">';

still not working...any ideas..again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$("#t").on("click", "#s", function() {
```

Your handler is being bound at run-time, and at the time your button isn't in the DOM.

Comment: still not working!! could it be from my jquery edition?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Aha! `.on` wasn't introduced until 1.7.2 - you need `.live` - https://api.jquery.com/live/ - `$("#s").live("click", function() {`

Comment: Voila! it worked!!!! another thing can you gimme the url to the new jquery?Thanks in advance

Comment: Just check out jQuery's site - jquery.com - they'll have it there. Be sure to mark the answer when ya can! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#t").on("click", "#s", function() { });
```

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

---

Attach event handler to the parent `#t` element so that when `#s` get added to DOM you click event works

Comment: still not working!! could it be from my jquery edition?

Answer (score 0):

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
is the thing

```
$("#t").on("click", "#s", function() {
  alert("clicked");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.load()` happens asynchronously, so it's *very likely* that your `.click()` assignment is being executed before the target element actually exists.  You can overcome this by assigning the handler to a parent element and delegating the event to that:

```
$('#t').on('click', '#s', function () {
    alert($("Done!");
});
```